# Функция for_each в библиотеке vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Нужно выполнить задание:

> Поменять знак у всех элементов массива между первым максимальным и последним максимальным элементами.

Подсказали с помощью функции `for_each` сделать. 
Но стоит вопрос, как передать функцию саму как аргумент в `for_each`?

Нашел вариант `void(*pfi)(int) = fun;`, не сработало.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>  

using namespace std;
void fun(vector<int> &v);
int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int N, k;
    cout << "Введите количество элементов" << endl;
cin >> N;
    vector <int> v(N);   

    cout << "Введите элементы" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  
    {
        cin >> v[i];                    
    }

    cout << "Значения второго вектора " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl<< "какому числу должно быть кратное? k= " << endl;
    cin >> k;
    double sum = 0;
    int kol = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <N; i++)
    {
        if (v[i]%k == 0) {
            sum += v[i];
            kol += 1;
        }
    }

    cout << sum / kol << endl;

    auto max =  *max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << "Максимум " << max << endl;
    void(*pfi)(int) = fun;


    auto kon = std::find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), max);
    if (kon != v.rend()) {
        std::for_each(max, kon, pfi);
    }

    _getch();
return 0;
}

void fun(vector<int> v) {
    int i;
    cout << v[i] * (-1);
}
```

Попытался сделать без этой функции, тоже показывает ошибку, ругается на `v[beg] *= -1;`

```
vector<int> fun(vector<int> v,vector<int>::iterator beg, vector<int>::iterator end) {
    while (beg != end)
    {
        v[beg] *= -1;
        beg++;

    }
    return v;

}
```

И как последний вопрос, нашел код в интернете:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Sum {
    Sum() { sum = 0; }
    void operator()(int n) { sum += n; }

    int sum;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums{3, 4, 2, 9, 15, 267};

    std::cout << "до: ";
    for (auto n : nums) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int &n){ n++; });
    Sum s = std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), Sum());

    std::cout << "после:  ";
    for (auto n : nums) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "сумма: " << s.sum << '\n';
}
```

Можете подсказать, что означает:

```
std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [](int &n){ n++; });
```

, т.е все, что стоит после квадратных скобок?

Comment: Как минимум `void fun(vector<int> v)` бессмысленно - знак меняется в *копии* вектора. И вообще, поясните, что означает "первый максимальный" и "последний максимальный" элементы... А после квадратных скобок - лямбда-функция, которая выполняет инкремент для каждого элемента...

Comment: а что означают сами квадратные скобки? Вот массив: 1 2 5 4 3 5 1 2 5 4. В нем максимум - 5. Первый раз он встречается на 3 позиции, последний раз - на 9. Между этими двумя позициями будет диапазон 4 3 5 1 2. А нельзя потом просто копию вектора вывести?

Comment: [](int &n){ n++; } это лямбда-функция, которая инкрементирует каждое значение вектора

Answer (score 1):

А зачем обязательно через `for_each`? вот такой способ - чем хуже?

```
void doit(vector<int>&v)
{
    if (v.empty()) return;
    int b = 0, e = 0, m = v[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (v[i] > m)        m = v[b = e = i];
        else if (v[i] == m)  e = i;
    }
    for(int i = b+1; i < e; ++i)
        v[i] = -v[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Оператор вектора `operator[]`  не может принимать итератор, а
   принимает беззнаковый целый тип(индекс), поэтому   `v[beg] *= -1;` 
   ошибка. Вместо этого должно быть `*beg = -1;`
2. И вы пытаетесь решать какую то другую задачу, не имеющую связь с
   заданием, которую нужно выполнить. Или же вы просто не смогли найти
   правильный подход.
   Ниже пример функции, которая может решать задачу тримя способами, последный из которых считаю вариантом лучше и проще, чем неоднократные вызовы функции и лишняя писанина. И, так как в задании не говорится о типах элементов, я ее сделал шаблонным:

   ```
   //некоторая функция
   template<typename T>
   void fun(T& i) { i *= 10; }        
   // режимы для решения задачи разными способами
   enum Mode{old_metod, new_metod, prefer_metod};

   // для массивов и контейнеров, поддерживающих двунаправленный итератор
   template < class Cont>
   void answer(Cont& v, Mode mode = prefer_metod )
   {
       auto first  = std::begin(v), last = std::end(v);
       if (first == last) return;
       // находим максимальный
       first = std::max_element(first, last);
       //находим последный элемент, имеющий такое значение
       while (*--last != *first);
       //если еще есть такой и они не соседные
       // то выполняем операцию над элементами между ними
       if (first++ != last) {
           using Tp = decltype(*first); //тип элементов
           switch (mode) {
           case old_metod:
               std::for_each(first, last,  std::ptr_fun(fun<Tp>));
               break;
           case new_metod:
               std::for_each(first, last, [](Tp& i) {i += 10;});
               break;
           default:
              while (first != last)
                  *first++ *= -1;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Осталось передать в функцию выбранный вами контейнер (можно массив) и режим

Comment: `Стандартные алгоритмы (std::for_each в том числе) не принимают указатели на функции` принимают https://ideone.com/wN9loS